# OAuth2 implementation for Facebook (or Twitter) mobile APP?

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0

Sorry for the misleading title, but here's I want to do:

1. Say I have an already running website *AwesomeWeb*, which authenticate its users using username/password combination. Now I want to develop a mobile app *AwesomeApp* for it, and at the same time, develop and open up its RESTful API - *AwesomeAPI*.
2. To keep things simple, I plan to authorize *AwesomeAPI* using OAuth2, and make *AwesomeApp* the first client/application.
3. But I **DO** wish *AwesomeApp* to have a simple sign-in process: input username/password -> click the button -> done. In other words, have a 'non-web' feel just like Facebook or Twitter does.
4. For those 3rd party mobile apps that want to access resources (like username) through *AwesomeAPI*, it should embed a button somewhere in the app, which opens *AwesomeApp* to display a 'allow/deny' page when clicked. Again, this is what Facebook and Twitter app doing.

OK, here's the questions:

- At step 3, what do I use: webview or doing http stuffs background or just use OAuth2 password grant type? Pros vs. cons?
- After step 3, I get an access token for *AwesomeApp*. But this token **CANNOT** be used in step 4 to issue an access token for some 3rd party app, am I right? If so, how to achieve step 4?

Appreciate your help a lot!

**Notes:** I'm not asking for OAuth2 flow or inter-app communication.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you achieve the step 3 by implementing "[Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)" flow defined in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (OAuth 2.0) or by other means, the authentication should be performed in the background. Note that in "Resource Owner Password Credentials" flow, a client application does not access the [authorization endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1) but accesses the [token endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2) directly, so the authorization UI (which is supposed to be shown at the authorization endpoint) is not displayed.

To achieve the step 4, you have to implement "[Authorization Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)" flow or "[Implicit](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2)" flow.